# Difference between using self and not using self in Swift init

Tags: properties, swift, initialization, self, convention

I noticed that initializing a property in a Swift initializer works using both:

```
self.property = 1
```

and

```
property = 1
```

Is there any difference between the two? If not, is there a convention that favors one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first you're making explicit that it's a class/struct property, whereas in the 2nd it's implicit. There's one big difference though: if there's a local variable with the same name (such as a parameter passed to the init), it will take precedence and hide the class/struct property.

As a matter of preference, I always prefer making it explicit, by using `self`. Also, by doing that I avoid common errors happening when I think I am accessing the class property, and I am using a local variable or function parameter instead.